# cloundfoundry vmc push of java web missing my jar files

Tags: classnotfoundexception, cloud-foundry

I have a few jars in my *WEB-INF/lib* folder and when I try to do a vmc push the application fails to deploy. After looking into the *Tomcat* logs I saw a `ClassNotFoundException` and it refers to one of the classes in my jar files. I can see the jar file in my local folder together with the class file in it, but when I browse the micro cloud folders I do not see some of the jar files

Thanks in advance for helping out. This is my stacktrace:

```
Aug 27, 2012 2:59:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Aug 27, 2012 2:59:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class     
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextCleanupListener.<clinit>(ContextCleanupListener.java:43)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4245)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4886)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4750)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1079)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1002)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    ... 27 more
```

Comment: Do you have other dependencies regarding logging like slf4j or log4j? Can you check if apache-commons-xyz.jar is included in your WAR archive that you push to CF?

Comment: Yes i do have the apache commons lib in my war but vmc push will not put this and few other jars into micro cloud deployment, i do see that the spring jars were pushed into the micro cloud instance, i did the war build with ANT and am pretty sure the war had all the other jars too, i will confirm and update once i am back home..

Comment: Can you provide your project structure here? Are you using Maven to manage your project dependencies? If so did you put the commons-logging dependency in the pom file?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was resolved when I removed the app and did one more push. BTW this was after I restarted the VM.